# Dynamic xpath in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anybody please tell me what is the difference between // and //* in xpath.
Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"//div[@id='something']"` - will find the div with id something.

`"//*[@id='something']"` - will find any tag with id something.

Answer (score 0):

Source-[Xpath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

//* Selects all elements in the document

//  Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

Comment: //*[@id=’social-media’] Does that means look for id='social-media' on every element.

Comment: That's correct.It would match the condition in all the tags and if you want to search in the current node then you have to use something like  //div[@id=’social-media’]

Answer (score 0):

//div[@id='xyz'] means find all div-s with the mentioned if ,// means that it is an relative Xpath and not an absolute one.

//*[@id='xyz'] find all element with the mentioned id not just div.Again it is an Relative Xpath as it starts with //